Strongswan as a IPSec/IKEv2 server for Android and iOS clients
Setting up Strongswan as a VPN IPSec/IKEv2 server
I want to setup a VPN server for my mobile devices to connect to my home network: smartphones (iPhone, Android), tablets (iPad) and laptops (Windows and Linux).
But both Android and iOS devies are unable to connect. How can I fix the configuration so that it works?
Netowrk schema
raspi5 (RaspiOS:bookworm) --- modem --- internet --- smartphone
desktop ___________________|                      |_ tablet
local_devices _____________|                      |_ laptop

modem: static public ip, private ip in 192.168.X.0/30 forward ports 500 and 4500 to raspi
raspi5: 2 static private ips on the same interface 192.168.X.0/30 and 192.168.Y.0/24, dhcp server and default gateway for the others home devices
Configurations
Server
On the raspi5 I've installed Strongswan (v 5.9.8) and configure as follow:
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

# basic configuration

config setup
    # strictcrlpolicy=yes
    uniqueids = no
    charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"

# Add connections here.

conn ikev2-vpn
    auto=add
    compress=no
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ikev2
    fragmentation=yes
    forceencaps=yes
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftid=192.168.X.x
    #leftid=81.56.120.104
    leftcert=server-cert.pem
    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightsourceip=192.168.Z.0/24
    rightdns=192.168.X.x,192.168.Y.y
    rightsendcert=never
    eap_identity=%identity

    ike=chacha20poly1305-sha512-curve25519-prfsha512,aes256gcm16-sha384-prfsha384-ecp384,aes256-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=chacha20poly1305-sha512,aes256gcm16-ecp384,aes256-sha256,aes256-sha1,3des-sha1!

server-cert.pem it's a certificate signed by a selfsigned CA already imported and enabled on my devices
Android

Type: IKEv2/IPSec MSCHAPv2
Server address: my.public.static.ip (the modem ones)
IPSec identifier: ikev2-vpn (something at random not sure what is needed for, is it ok?)
IPSec CA certificate: my selfsigned CA cert
IPSec server certificate: (recieved from server)
Username: the username from ipsec.secrets
Password: the password from ipsec.secrets

Trying connecting
When trying connecting to the server from my devices it's always unsuccessful here the logs:
Android
# tcpdump -n '(udp port 500) or (udp port 4500)' -vvv
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes

09:05:19.801204 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 57, id 47442, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 1100)
    android.public.ip.address.7540 > server.local.ip.address.500: [udp sum ok] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie eb888521dbd62292->0000000000000000: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]:
    (sa: len=404
        (p: #1 protoid=isakmp transform=21 len=200
            (t: #1 type=encr id=#13 (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #2 type=encr id=aes (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #3 type=encr id=#13 (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #4 type=encr id=aes (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #5 type=encr id=#13 (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #6 type=encr id=aes (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #7 type=integ id=#14 )
            (t: #8 type=integ id=#13 )
            (t: #9 type=integ id=#12 )
            (t: #10 type=integ id=aes-xcbc )
            (t: #11 type=integ id=#8 )
            (t: #12 type=dh id=modp4096 )
            (t: #13 type=dh id=#31 )
            (t: #14 type=dh id=modp3072 )
            (t: #15 type=dh id=modp2048 )
            (t: #16 type=prf id=hmac-sha )
            (t: #17 type=prf id=aes128_xcbc )
            (t: #18 type=prf id=#5 )
            (t: #19 type=prf id=#6 )
            (t: #20 type=prf id=#7 )
            (t: #21 type=prf id=#8 ))
        (p: #2 protoid=isakmp transform=20 len=204
            (t: #1 type=encr id=#28 )
            (t: #2 type=encr id=#20 (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #3 type=encr id=#19 (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #4 type=encr id=#18 (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #5 type=encr id=#20 (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #6 type=encr id=#19 (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #7 type=encr id=#18 (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #8 type=encr id=#20 (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #9 type=encr id=#19 (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #10 type=encr id=#18 (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #11 type=dh id=modp4096 )
            (t: #12 type=dh id=#31 )
            (t: #13 type=dh id=modp3072 )
            (t: #14 type=dh id=modp2048 )
            (t: #15 type=prf id=hmac-sha )
            (t: #16 type=prf id=aes128_xcbc )
            (t: #17 type=prf id=#5 )
            (t: #18 type=prf id=#6 )
            (t: #19 type=prf id=#7 )
            (t: #20 type=prf id=#8 )))
    (v2ke: len=512 group=modp4096 )
    (nonce: len=32 nonce=() )
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16388(nat_detection_source_ip))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16389(nat_detection_destination_ip))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16430(status))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16431(status))
09:05:19.801872 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63842, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 66)
    server.local.ip.address.500 > android.public.ip.address.7540: [bad udp cksum 0xb3fe -> 0x71c8!] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie eb888521dbd62292->0000000000000000: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]:
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=17(invalid_ke_payload))
09:05:20.343778 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 57, id 47555, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 1100)
    android.public.ip.address.7540 > server.local.ip.address.500: [udp sum ok] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie eb888521dbd62292->0000000000000000: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]:
    (sa: len=404
        (p: #1 protoid=isakmp transform=21 len=200
            (t: #1 type=encr id=#13 (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #2 type=encr id=aes (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #3 type=encr id=#13 (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #4 type=encr id=aes (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #5 type=encr id=#13 (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #6 type=encr id=aes (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #7 type=integ id=#14 )
            (t: #8 type=integ id=#13 )
            (t: #9 type=integ id=#12 )
            (t: #10 type=integ id=aes-xcbc )
            (t: #11 type=integ id=#8 )
            (t: #12 type=dh id=modp4096 )
            (t: #13 type=dh id=#31 )
            (t: #14 type=dh id=modp3072 )
            (t: #15 type=dh id=modp2048 )
            (t: #16 type=prf id=hmac-sha )
            (t: #17 type=prf id=aes128_xcbc )
            (t: #18 type=prf id=#5 )
            (t: #19 type=prf id=#6 )
            (t: #20 type=prf id=#7 )
            (t: #21 type=prf id=#8 ))
        (p: #2 protoid=isakmp transform=20 len=204
            (t: #1 type=encr id=#28 )
            (t: #2 type=encr id=#20 (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #3 type=encr id=#19 (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #4 type=encr id=#18 (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #5 type=encr id=#20 (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #6 type=encr id=#19 (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #7 type=encr id=#18 (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #8 type=encr id=#20 (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #9 type=encr id=#19 (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #10 type=encr id=#18 (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #11 type=dh id=modp4096 )
            (t: #12 type=dh id=#31 )
            (t: #13 type=dh id=modp3072 )
            (t: #14 type=dh id=modp2048 )
            (t: #15 type=prf id=hmac-sha )
            (t: #16 type=prf id=aes128_xcbc )
            (t: #17 type=prf id=#5 )
            (t: #18 type=prf id=#6 )
            (t: #19 type=prf id=#7 )
            (t: #20 type=prf id=#8 )))
    (v2ke: len=512 group=modp4096 )
    (nonce: len=32 nonce=() )
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16388(nat_detection_source_ip))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16389(nat_detection_destination_ip))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16430(status))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16431(status))
09:05:20.344349 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63912, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 66)
    server.local.ip.address.500 > android.public.ip.address.7540: [bad udp cksum 0xb3fe -> 0x71c8!] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie eb888521dbd62292->0000000000000000: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]:
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=17(invalid_ke_payload))
09:05:20.365424 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 57, id 47564, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 844)
    android.public.ip.address.7541 > server.local.ip.address.500: [udp sum ok] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie a9c211c9a1f5c955->0000000000000000: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]:
    (sa: len=404
        (p: #1 protoid=isakmp transform=21 len=200
            (t: #1 type=encr id=#13 (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #2 type=encr id=aes (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #3 type=encr id=#13 (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #4 type=encr id=aes (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #5 type=encr id=#13 (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #6 type=encr id=aes (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #7 type=integ id=#14 )
            (t: #8 type=integ id=#13 )
            (t: #9 type=integ id=#12 )
            (t: #10 type=integ id=aes-xcbc )
            (t: #11 type=integ id=#8 )
            (t: #12 type=dh id=modp4096 )
            (t: #13 type=dh id=#31 )
            (t: #14 type=dh id=modp3072 )
            (t: #15 type=dh id=modp2048 )
            (t: #16 type=prf id=hmac-sha )
            (t: #17 type=prf id=aes128_xcbc )
            (t: #18 type=prf id=#5 )
            (t: #19 type=prf id=#6 )
            (t: #20 type=prf id=#7 )
            (t: #21 type=prf id=#8 ))
        (p: #2 protoid=isakmp transform=20 len=204
            (t: #1 type=encr id=#28 )
            (t: #2 type=encr id=#20 (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #3 type=encr id=#19 (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #4 type=encr id=#18 (type=keylen value=0100))
            (t: #5 type=encr id=#20 (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #6 type=encr id=#19 (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #7 type=encr id=#18 (type=keylen value=00c0))
            (t: #8 type=encr id=#20 (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #9 type=encr id=#19 (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #10 type=encr id=#18 (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #11 type=dh id=modp4096 )
            (t: #12 type=dh id=#31 )
            (t: #13 type=dh id=modp3072 )
            (t: #14 type=dh id=modp2048 )
            (t: #15 type=prf id=hmac-sha )
            (t: #16 type=prf id=aes128_xcbc )
            (t: #17 type=prf id=#5 )
            (t: #18 type=prf id=#6 )
            (t: #19 type=prf id=#7 )
            (t: #20 type=prf id=#8 )))
    (v2ke: len=256 group=modp2048 )
    (nonce: len=32 nonce=() )
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16388(nat_detection_source_ip))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16389(nat_detection_destination_ip))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16430(status))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16431(status))
09:05:20.368869 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63918, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 500)
    server.local.ip.address.500 > android.public.ip.address.7541: [bad udp cksum 0xb5b0 -> 0x5b20!] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie a9c211c9a1f5c955->b3326e36bf2c9701: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]:
    (sa: len=44
        (p: #1 protoid=isakmp transform=4 len=44
            (t: #1 type=encr id=aes (type=keylen value=0080))
            (t: #2 type=integ id=#12 )
            (t: #3 type=prf id=#5 )
            (t: #4 type=dh id=modp2048 )))
    (v2ke: len=256 group=modp2048 )
    (nonce: len=32 nonce=() )
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16388(nat_detection_source_ip))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16389(nat_detection_destination_ip))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16430(status))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16431(status))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16418(status))
    (n: prot_id=#0 type=16404(status))
09:05:20.647603 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 57, id 1, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 29)
    android.public.ip.address.7543 > server.local.ip.address.4500: [no cksum] isakmp-nat-keep-alive
09:05:20.647753 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 57, id 47596, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 576)
    android.public.ip.address.7545 > server.local.ip.address.4500: [udp sum ok] NONESP-encap: isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000001 cookie a9c211c9a1f5c955->b3326e36bf2c9701: child_sa  ikev2_auth[I]:
    (v2e: len=512 )
09:05:20.669438 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63927, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 112)
    server.local.ip.address.4500 > android.public.ip.address.7545: [bad udp cksum 0xb42c -> 0x6bd4!] NONESP-encap: isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000001 cookie a9c211c9a1f5c955->b3326e36bf2c9701: child_sa  ikev2_auth[R]:
    (v2e: len=48 )

# journalctl
09:05:15 server-hostname kernel: macb 1f00100000.ethernet eth0: entered promiscuous mode
09:05:19 server-hostname charon[127126]: 13[NET] received packet: from android.public.ip.address[7540] to server.local.ip.address[500] (1072 bytes)
09:05:19 server-hostname charon[127126]: 13[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) ]
09:05:19 server-hostname charon[127126]: 13[IKE] android.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:05:19 server-hostname charon[127126]: 13[IKE] android.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:05:19 server-hostname charon[127126]: 13[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
09:05:19 server-hostname charon[127126]: 13[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
09:05:19 server-hostname charon[127126]: 13[IKE] DH group MODP_4096 unacceptable, requesting MODP_2048
09:05:19 server-hostname charon[127126]: 13[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(INVAL_KE) ]
09:05:19 server-hostname charon[127126]: 13[NET] sending packet: from server.local.ip.address[500] to android.public.ip.address[7540] (38 bytes)
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 14[NET] received packet: from android.public.ip.address[7540] to server.local.ip.address[500] (1072 bytes)
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 14[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) ]
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 14[IKE] android.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 14[IKE] android.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 14[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 14[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 14[IKE] DH group MODP_4096 unacceptable, requesting MODP_2048
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 14[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(INVAL_KE) ]
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 14[NET] sending packet: from server.local.ip.address[500] to android.public.ip.address[7540] (38 bytes)
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 15[NET] received packet: from android.public.ip.address[7541] to server.local.ip.address[500] (816 bytes)
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 15[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) ]
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 15[IKE] android.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 15[IKE] android.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 15[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 15[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 15[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(CHDLESS_SUP) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 15[NET] sending packet: from server.local.ip.address[500] to android.public.ip.address[7541] (472 bytes)
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[NET] received packet: from android.public.ip.address[7545] to server.local.ip.address[4500] (544 bytes)
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi IDr N(MOBIKE_SUP) SA TSi TSr CPRQ(ADDR ADDR6 DNS DNS6 MASK VER) ]
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[IKE] peer supports MOBIKE
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
09:05:20 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[NET] sending packet: from server.local.ip.address[4500] to android.public.ip.address[7545] (80 bytes)
09:05:25 server-hostname kernel: macb 1f00100000.ethernet eth0: left promiscuous mode

iOS
# tcpdump -n '(udp port 500) or (udp port 4500)' -vvv
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes

09:21:36.952657 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 57, id 3265, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 398)
    ios.public.ip.address.28563 > server.local.ip.address.500: [udp sum ok] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie 79c6c3d8306c5c9a->0000000000000000: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]:
    
09:21:36.953312 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25610, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 66)
    server.local.ip.address.500 > ios.public.ip.address.28563: [bad udp cksum 0xf50b -> 0x8309!] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie 79c6c3d8306c5c9a->0000000000000000: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]:
    
09:21:37.107647 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 57, id 17593, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 590)
    ios.public.ip.address.28563 > server.local.ip.address.500: [udp sum ok] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie 79c6c3d8306c5c9a->0000000000000000: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]:
    
09:21:37.111165 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25632, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 500)
    server.local.ip.address.500 > ios.public.ip.address.28563: [bad udp cksum 0xf6bd -> 0x8272!] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie 79c6c3d8306c5c9a->302ec77485b0d33e: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]:
    
09:21:37.237414 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 57, id 21341, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 400)
    ios.public.ip.address.28575 > server.local.ip.address.4500: [udp sum ok] NONESP-encap: isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000001 cookie 79c6c3d8306c5c9a->302ec77485b0d33e: child_sa  ikev2_auth[I]:
    (v2e: len=336 )
09:21:37.259191 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25640, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 112)
    server.local.ip.address.4500 > ios.public.ip.address.28575: [bad udp cksum 0xf539 -> 0x595e!] NONESP-encap: isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000001 cookie 79c6c3d8306c5c9a->302ec77485b0d33e: child_sa  ikev2_auth[R]:
    (v2e: len=48 )
09:21:37.375952 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 57, id 31297, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 398)
    ios.public.ip.address.28563 > server.local.ip.address.500: [udp sum ok] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie f35c26cfc2577a80->0000000000000000: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]:
    
09:21:37.376433 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25651, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 66)
    server.local.ip.address.500 > ios.public.ip.address.28563: [bad udp cksum 0xf50b -> 0xf6aa!] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie f35c26cfc2577a80->0000000000000000: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]:
    
09:21:37.538005 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 57, id 8345, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 590)
    ios.public.ip.address.28563 > server.local.ip.address.500: [udp sum ok] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie f35c26cfc2577a80->0000000000000000: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]:
    
09:21:37.541420 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25671, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 500)
    server.local.ip.address.500 > ios.public.ip.address.28563: [bad udp cksum 0xf6bd -> 0x1d5b!] isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000000 cookie f35c26cfc2577a80->8b8353a9949e18f6: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]:
    
09:21:37.682796 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 57, id 26036, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 400)
    ios.public.ip.address.28575 > server.local.ip.address.4500: [udp sum ok] NONESP-encap: isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000001 cookie f35c26cfc2577a80->8b8353a9949e18f6: child_sa  ikev2_auth[I]:
    
09:21:37.704385 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25683, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 112)
    server.local.ip.address.4500 > ios.public.ip.address.28575: [bad udp cksum 0xf539 -> 0x1b71!] NONESP-encap: isakmp 2.0 msgid 00000001 cookie f35c26cfc2577a80->8b8353a9949e18f6: child_sa  ikev2_auth[R]:
    

# journalctl
09:20:01 server-hostname CRON[154775]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
09:20:01 server-hostname CRON[154776]: (root) CMD (( /home/rez/hub-ctrl/uhubctl/coolme.sh >> /home/rez/hub-ctrl/uhubctl/log.txt ))
09:20:02 server-hostname CRON[154775]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
09:21:01 server-hostname CRON[154792]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
09:21:01 server-hostname CRON[154793]: (root) CMD (( /home/rez/hub-ctrl/uhubctl/coolme.sh >> /home/rez/hub-ctrl/uhubctl/log.txt ))
09:21:01 server-hostname CRON[154792]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
09:21:03 server-hostname kernel: macb 1f00100000.ethernet eth0: entered promiscuous mode
09:21:36 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[NET] received packet: from ios.public.ip.address[28563] to server.local.ip.address[500] (370 bytes)
09:21:36 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(REDIR_SUP) N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) ]
09:21:36 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[IKE] ios.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:21:36 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[IKE] ios.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:21:36 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
09:21:36 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
09:21:36 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[IKE] DH group ECP_256 unacceptable, requesting MODP_2048
09:21:36 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(INVAL_KE) ]
09:21:36 server-hostname charon[127126]: 01[NET] sending packet: from server.local.ip.address[500] to ios.public.ip.address[28563] (38 bytes)
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 06[NET] received packet: from ios.public.ip.address[28563] to server.local.ip.address[500] (562 bytes)
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 06[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(REDIR_SUP) N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) ]
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 06[IKE] ios.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 06[IKE] ios.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 06[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 06[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 06[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(CHDLESS_SUP) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 06[NET] sending packet: from server.local.ip.address[500] to ios.public.ip.address[28563] (472 bytes)
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 05[NET] received packet: from ios.public.ip.address[28575] to server.local.ip.address[4500] (368 bytes)
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 05[ENC] unknown attribute type INTERNAL_DNS_DOMAIN
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 05[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) IDr CPRQ(ADDR MASK DHCP DNS ADDR6 DHCP6 DNS6 DOMAIN) N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) N(NON_FIRST_FRAG) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) ]
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 05[IKE] peer supports MOBIKE
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 05[IKE] received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 05[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 05[NET] sending packet: from server.local.ip.address[4500] to ios.public.ip.address[28575] (80 bytes)
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 07[NET] received packet: from ios.public.ip.address[28563] to server.local.ip.address[500] (370 bytes)
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 07[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(REDIR_SUP) N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) ]
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 07[IKE] ios.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 07[IKE] ios.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 07[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 07[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 07[IKE] DH group ECP_256 unacceptable, requesting MODP_2048
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 07[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(INVAL_KE) ]
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 07[NET] sending packet: from server.local.ip.address[500] to ios.public.ip.address[28563] (38 bytes)
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 09[NET] received packet: from ios.public.ip.address[28563] to server.local.ip.address[500] (562 bytes)
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 09[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(REDIR_SUP) N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) ]
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 09[IKE] ios.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 09[IKE] ios.public.ip.address is initiating an IKE_SA
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 09[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 09[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 09[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(CHDLESS_SUP) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 09[NET] sending packet: from server.local.ip.address[500] to ios.public.ip.address[28563] (472 bytes)
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 11[NET] received packet: from ios.public.ip.address[28575] to server.local.ip.address[4500] (368 bytes)
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 11[ENC] unknown attribute type INTERNAL_DNS_DOMAIN
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 11[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) IDr CPRQ(ADDR MASK DHCP DNS ADDR6 DHCP6 DNS6 DOMAIN) N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) N(NON_FIRST_FRAG) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) ]
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 11[IKE] peer supports MOBIKE
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 11[IKE] received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 11[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
09:21:37 server-hostname charon[127126]: 11[NET] sending packet: from server.local.ip.address[4500] to ios.public.ip.address[28575] (80 bytes)
09:21:53 server-hostname kernel: macb 1f00100000.ethernet eth0: left promiscuous mode

full tcpdump logs at https://gist.github.com/lucarez/c84c1ac4394f04efea19c51033c6ecea

Please don't use cfg 0 this will hide the exact log messages that would probably explain what the issue is.

@ecdsa should I just remove it or change it to something else?

Either remove it so the default log level of  1 applies, or even set it to 2 as you are currently debugging a config issue.
